# My file explorer's crashing everytime i right click on some file, How do i fix it?

Tags: windows-explorer

My file explorer's crashing every time I right-clicked on some files, it shows the loading circle instead of the Option like open, run administrator, etc. then the file explorer stops working, I can't even click the X to close the window

I have to go to the task manager to restart the windows explorer just to get away with it.

it's working fine unless I right-click a file or double left click an application, photo, video, text doc. etc.

Comment: Specific files or any files?

Comment: You clearly have a shell extension installed that is locking up the explorer.  If we knew WHAT KIND OF FILE (as @Ramhound has eluded to) we might be able to help you either reassign it or strip it without needing to run a repair install.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Explorer is working fine unless I right-click a file or double left click an application, photo, video, text doc ...

I have seen this and the reason is usually an issue with the context system.

You can look at context settings with Nirsoft Shell Menu View, but there are so many contexts that will like be fruitless.

Dropbox and WinMerge both use contexts  extensively.

Try a Windows 10 Repair Install but first fully exit DropBox and (if you use it) uninstall WinMerge.

Note the 3 possible methods to Repair Install. Start with Keep Everything and see if that works.

> Go to the Media Creation Link:
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: A repair install for a misbehaving shell extension seems a little harsh.  No offense meant @John.

Comment: I have seen this before and if shell extensions are messed up, repair install is a trouble-free way to fix. Keep Everything is simple to do and only takes some time.

Comment: I guess I take for granted the understanding of how shell extensions work.  I have written many of them.  I am thinking now that you are probably correct (you usually are).

Comment: How we diagnose the problem before suggesting they reinstall Windows?

Comment: A repair install is a repair - not a Windows Reinstall - at least not how I use the terminology.

Comment: +1 on the post. Enough helpful ideas to troubleshoot with a method to restore.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for answering, so I downloaded the media creation and I don't know what to pick to proceed with, so I accepted the license and they're two option to pick which is "upgrade this pc now" or "create installation media ( USB Flash Drive, DVD, or ISO ) for another PC" if I pick the second option it then lead me to pick another two option which is "USB Flash Drive or ISO file" 

I assumed and I chose "USB Flash drive" but then it says "we can't find a USB flash drive. so do I need to insert USB to proceed? I wanna make sure and do this safe, I'm a bit scared tbh. Thank youu

Comment: With the second option, you can Open (I do this) or save to USB (I have done that). Yes - you need to insert a blank USB key.  If you choose this route, once the USB has been created, leave it in, leave Windows 10 running and then run Setup from the USB key. That works as well